# @ModelAttribute in Controller does not auto increment ID

Tags: spring, hibernate, modelattribute

I am working on Spring web based project and I am having trouble with @ModelAttribute that return model object to JSP file to be filled then it will be passed to controller function then data will be saved to database. Let me show you some code.

It is my Software Engineering Course Project for more detailed information code is available on github:
https://github.com/IYTECENG316SoftwareEngineering/reddit

```
@Controller
    public class MessageController {



     @ModelAttribute("privateMessage")
         public PrivateMessage constructPrivateMessage() {
         return new PrivateMessage();
     }




    @RequestMapping(value = "/message/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "sendMessage")
        public String doSendMessage(Model model, @PathVariable("id") int id,
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("privateMessage") PrivateMessage privateMessage, BindingResult result,Principal principal) {

            if (result.hasErrors()) {
                return showMessage(model,id);
            }


         User messageOwner = userService.findOne(principal.getName());
                //I need to create new instance of PrivateMessage because
                //(@ModelAttribute("privateMessage") PrivateMessage privateMessage) this gives always same ID.
                PrivateMessage message = new PrivateMessage();
                message.setMessage(privateMessage.getMessage());
                message.setUser(messageOwner);

            PrivateMessageConversation conversation = messageService.findOneWithMessages(id);
            message.setPrivateMessageConversation(conversation);
            messageService.save(message);

            return "redirect:/message/"+message.getID()+".html";
        }

    }
```

PrivateMessage object send to jsp file and it filled send back to doSendMessage function with @ModelAttribute. Object come with filled (all the inputs written in to object perfectly) but only problem is that its ID is not auto-incremented. There is one more code that I want to show. We use same template for topic and it works perfectly.Here the code;

```
@Controller
public class UserController {


@ModelAttribute("topic")
    public Topic contructTopic() {
        return new Topic();
    }
@ModelAttribute("entry")
public Entry contructEntry() {
    return new Entry();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/account", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doAddNewTopic(Model model,
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("topic") Topic topic,
            BindingResult resultTopic, Principal principal,
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("entry") Entry entry,
            BindingResult resultEntry,
            @RequestParam("topic_category") String category_string) {
        System.out.println(principal.getName() + " " + category_string + " "
                + topic.getTitle() + " " + entry.getDescription());

        if (resultTopic.hasErrors()) {
            return account(model, principal);
        }
        if (resultEntry.hasErrors()) {
            return account(model, principal);
        }

        String name = principal.getName();

        Category category = categoryService.findByName(category_string);
        topic.setCategory(category);
        topicService.save(topic);

        entry.setTopic(topic);
        entry.setPublishedDate(new LocalDateTime());
        entryService.save(entry, name);

        return "redirect:/topic/" + topic.getId() + ".html";
    }

}
```

Above code work perfectly. Topic and entry object send to jsp, they filled and send back to controller and all their attributes fine and IDs are auto-incremented. We could not figure auto why first one is not working.

NOTE: We are using Hibernate, Spring Data JPA and Tiles

Answer (score 0):

In your first controller (`MessageController`) you are constructing a new instance of `PrivateMessage` and saving that. The hibernate generated id will be changed there. Then you are doing a redirect with a path pattern (`redirect:/message/{id}.html`). The pattern will be expanded with the original id the method `doSendMessage` has been called with.

In your second (working) controller you are not creating a new instance of `Topic`, so after saving topic the hibernate assigned id is contained in your topic. After that you are also not using springs path expansion but constructing a path by hand using the new id.

Change your first controller from

```
return "redirect:/message/{id}.html";
```

to

```
return "redirect:/message/" + message.getId() + ".html";
```

or

```
return UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("redirect:/message/{id}.html")
    .buildAndExpand(message.getId())
    .encode()
    .toUriString()
```

Comment: Hi @DirkLachowski. Thank your for interest.You are right I have some "problem" with redirect but they were work. Anyway I changed as you recommend to ` return "redirect:/message/"+ message.getId() + ".html"; `
I think my redirections are fine now.
Yes, in my  **MessageController** I create new instance of **PrivateMessage** because it always come with same ID. I hope I can tell my problem correctly.
Other hand,
**second (working) controller** I do not create new instance because it comes with auto-generated ID and now I am trying to understand why one works and the other does not.